# How to create my class to persist a Document in MongoDB using Java

Tags: java, json, mongodb, nosql

I have this JSON:

```
{
  'name': 'Ana',
  'lastName':'Lee',
  'address': {
     'street':'321 Malvo St',
     'city':'Nowhere',
     'state':'MA',
     'zip':'010101'
   }
 }
```

I need to persist using MongoDB Driver in Java.
How should I create field 'address' in my class?

```
 @Document(collection = "user")
 public class User extends AbstractEntity{

       private String name;

       private String lastName;

       private ????? address

       ...
  }
```

**address type ?????, should be:** 
   - a new class Address with fields street, city, etc.. 
   - a Document 
   - a String 
   - a Map 
   - other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new Address class,

```
    class Adderss {
      private String street;
      private String city;
      private String state;
      private String zip;

      //getters and setters
   }
```

Then you can use it in your User class,

```
private Address address;
```

Or else you can use a java.util.Map for this.

```
private Map<String, String> address;
```

Both works fine but if you need to use those address details in your logic. I recommend you to use Address class.